# How do I add a custom config file to .Net 7 function app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I am trying to add a custom json file to the function app. I can successfully work with it on local but as soon as I publish the app to azure I get the error after running the function. Its a queue triggered function.

config file looks like:

```
{
  "DbConfig": {
    "ConnectionString": ""
  },
  "EmailConfig": {
    "Key": "",
    "From": "",
    "TimeZone": ""
  },
  "QueueConfig": {
    "QueueName": "",
    "ConnectionString""
  }
}
```

Program.cs looks like

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults();


IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                       .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                       .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                       .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                       .Build();

var host = builder.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
{
    serviceCollection.Configure<ConfigurationSettings>(configuration);
    var config = configuration.Get<ConfigurationSettings>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(config.DbConfig);
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(config.EmailConfig);
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(config.QueueConfig);

    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DomainContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.DbConfig.ConnectionString));

    serviceCollection.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    serviceCollection.ConfigureServices();
    serviceCollection.ConfigureRepositories();
    serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}).Build();

host.Run()
```

Error I get on the logs is: **Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'config.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\config.json'.**

I have tried alot of things and changed the property of the file to copy always, copy if newer.

But no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"I have tried alot of things and changed the property of the file to copy always, copy if newer. But no luck"` You should change both property of `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy If newer`.

Comment: I did that, changed it to content, embedded resource. nothing worked. I actually resolved by manually creating the file through Kudu and it works fine. I tried it before but for some reason it wasnt being picked up by the function.

Comment: That's the way, Anyway glad to see you have resolved it.

Comment: Its quite alright  and you have done it.